# Edit WordPress post content from the database

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I had to restore a database from a dump due to technical issues. It works well, however my client edited a long post that wasn't written yet in the dump I used. I managed to retrieve this specific post content from a more recent dump but I'm struggling to update the original post with the new content I retrieved. Restoring this recent dump isn't an option as the website was already broken by then, I only want the post content.

I copy-pasted the content of the `post_content` column (from wp_posts table) into the matching row of the old dump (same ID, with post_status set to `publish`). The issue is that I don't see the new content anywhere, the editor still shows me the old version.

I cleared the cache through the WP Super Cache plugin and I also tried to make a tiny update in the post title to see if it would take the changes I made in the database. The title update made the revision tool show me my new content as being the "current version", which is great, but there's no improvement besides that: both the editor and the published post show the old content. My client uses Elementor and I couldn't find any way to edit the post as HTML when using this plugin.

I am new to WordPress and I'm running out of ideas. Is there something else that I need to do to have WordPress acknowledge a change made through the database?